# Pycharm warning that variable is unused

Tags: python, scope

I am not very familiar with Python, especially with the scope of variables. I am trying to access a sqlite database. However, Pycharm's code inspection is warning me that the variable `data` is not being used.

```
def getIndexFromDB(self, user, username, domID):
    data = None #warning that this variable is unused
    with lite.connect(self.DBName) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
        cur.execute('select idx from Upass where username = ? and uname = ? and dom = ?', (user, username, domID))
        data = cur.fetchone()
    return data
```

Is this a pycharm problem?

Comment: No, it's because you never use the value of `data = None`. You just reassign it.

Comment: Usually Pycharm will like this style better if you label initiate self.data = Nonewhen you create your object in __init__(self, *args)

Comment: @JeffM: It's a local variable, not an instance attribute.

Comment: its got nothing to do with pycharm...i tried it in pydev/eclipse and it gives the same warning..so must be pylint (or something similar) that's throwing it off...

Comment: I think this is a bug with the code inspector, as it is theoretically possible for `data = cur.fetchone()`  not to be executed **and** `return data` to be executed. -- https://gist.github.com/Dunes/da9ad871b91f6f3b0f55

Comment: @Dunes That is an interesting snippet!  I had not considered this possibility, and I think it could be worth converting your comment into an answer given that the currently accepted answer will also NameError out in this strange case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use the below code instead of assigning data at the very top? Thats safe and cures the warning as well...

```
def getIndexFromDB(self, user, username, domID):
    with lite.connect(self.DBName) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
        cur.execute('select idx from Upass where username = ? and uname = ? and dom = ?', (user, username, domID))
        data = cur.fetchone()
    data = data or None
    return data
```

Comment: So in python, the data variable, even though is initialized in the loop, is available anywhere in the function?

Comment: I don't see a loop here..do you mean "with" statement? yes...its available outside if initialized within the with statement

Comment: Why `data = data or None`? Why would you want to replace certain values of `data` with `None`?

Comment: Read the original code snippet...if data was not assigned, he wants to default it to None..and return None....Alternatively, you can just say "return data or None"

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer `return data or None`, but they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: @user2357112 `fetchone` returns a tuple of data, so as long as there is any data present, `data` will be truthy.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is correct.

Assigning `data = None` is a useless line and may as well be deleted.

```
def getIndexFromDB(self, user, username, domID):
    with lite.connect(self.DBName) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
        cur.execute('select idx from Upass where username = ? and uname = ? and dom = ?', (user, username, domID))
        return cur.fetchone()
```

The code above is equivalent, because the function `getIndexFromDB` can only exit in one of three possible ways:

- An unhandled exception is raised (no return value)
- An exception is raised inside the indented block, but marked as handled by the `__exit__` method of the context manager (`None` is returned). That can not happen in *this particular code* because this db context manager, presumably from sqlite, is not swallowing exceptions. But it's worth to keep in mind in other cases.
- No errors. The result of `cur.fetchone()` is returned, [which itself might be `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) in case of no data.

Comment: Right, I forgot that `fetchone` returns `None` in the case of no data.

Comment: A function that expects to return a value should always explicitly `return None` rather than relying on that default behaviour. Otherwise, it's not easy to understand that the function my intentionally execute in a given way and return none.

Comment: @Dunes It is [`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) that can also return `None` in this case. No need to add a useless `return None` anywhere here.